# What іs a suіt vіolatіon? How do they provide advantages?

Tags: olympics, skiing

I was watchіng the Olympіcs, and the broadcast team durіng the skі jumpіng event mentіoned a "suit violation." At fіrst, I thought they meant "wardrobe malfunctіon." However, іt actually cost Japan a medal.

According to [this article](https://www.nbcolympics.com/news/japanese-ski-jumper-apologizes-suit-violation):

> Ski jumping has complex and controversial rules that link suit size and ski length to bodyweight in an attempt to remove any advantage that might be gained by athletes being lighter and tiny weight changes can have a significant impact.

How does suit size and/or ski length that constitute a suit violation provide advantages?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the suits can provide buoyancy and aerodynamic advantage - ie, they help the ski jumpers stay in the air longer.  [This CBS News article goes into some detail](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/winter-olympics-2014-the-fine-line-between-innovation-and-technological-doping/).  For example:

> According to current rules, at least 40 liters of air must be able to pass through the fabric, so that the suits cannot hold too much air or become buoyant.

Further, extra fabric provides an advantage as well:

> Too much fabric also offered an advantage. "Adding that surface area to your flight position can make 10 meters difference," says Johnson. In the early 2000s, the suits "changed at least once a year or twice for three years while they experimented with trying to come up with the optimal suit for safety and fairness."

Ski length affects [how fast the skier is able to travel on the snow](https://newtoski.com/short-vs-long-skis/) - longer skis make you go faster - and the big problem there is that faster skiers run more risk of injury or death.  The aerodynamics also contributes here, as skiers want to go faster to jump further, but the skintight suits mean they land faster, also.

> But tighter suits required the skiers to travel faster in order to jump as far. And since they started skiing faster, there have been more injuries. After this year's Olympics, Johnson says, FIS will be looking into overall safety of the skintight suits.